# How should I determine what is issuing a flush_all command

Tags: memcached

We have a memcached server that is shared by about two dozen apps.  One of the web apps (or perhaps one of our utility apps) is issuing a flush_all command periodically.  The frequency seems random, or at least we haven't seen a pattern yet.  It happens about 10 times an hour.

Here's the rub.  I can't figure out a good way to figure out which app is doing this. The memcacehd logs are not helpful at all. Here's what I've done so far:
* grep all source code - Other than memcached libraries I can't see anywhere where we issue this command.
* Enable verbose logging (-vv) in memcached - I see the commands get issued, but the log doesn't show any information about where the command is being issued from.
* Research how to administratively disable this; without an unapproved source patch to memcached I can't figure out a good way to do it.

Has anyone else had this problem?  I'm assuming that this is coming from one of our web apps, but its possible its from somewhere else too.  Any suggestions?

My next step is to setup a second memcached server and move applications one by one (which will be slow and time consuming).  There must be a better way.

Comment: One more quick note:  I'm sure these are not happening because the cache is full.  To test it, I restarted the server (which clears everything) and verified that flushes were occurring prior to the server reaching its maximum allocated ram.

Comment: Not sure if that qualifies for an answer, but you could just attach gdb to memcached process and set breakpoint on the function/line where flush_all is handled. Or use wireshark with lots of memory.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but in case anyone else hits this...

I'd suggest you set up multiple memcache proxies and configure each application to use a different one. The first proxy I found was [twemproxy](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/twemproxy), no idea how good it is.

After that you can use the logs for the proxy to identify which application is issuing the commands.